# How to mount cifs share read-write?

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I am nearly positive the fstab entry is correct here, but when the cifs share is mounted, it is read only. What could I be missing?

`/etc/fstab` entry:

```
//192.168.1.200/music/ /home/erik/Music-Bespin cifs credentials=/home/erik/.smbcredentials,noperm,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

And here is the corresponding `smb.conf̀` server side

```
[global]
    server string = samba_server
    server role = standalone server
    interfaces = lo eno1
    bind interfaces only = yes
    disable netbios = yes
    smb ports = 445
    log file = /var/log/samba/smb.log
    max log size = 10000
[music]
    path = /home/erik/Shared/Music
    valid users = erik
    read only = no
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    public = yes
    force create mode = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
    force user = nobody
    guest ok = yes
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the Unix permissions on `/home/erik/Shared/Music`?

Answer (score 2):

A CIFS mount cannot override the permissions settings of Samba or the underlying Linux permissions.

Your "music" share definition allows only "erik" access to the share. Since the Music subfolder - on the server - is likely owned by "erik" everything should work.

Except you stipulated `force user = nobody` in your share definition. That "forces" "erik" to become "nobody" which likely has no write access to that folder.

Either remove the `force user = nobody` line from your [music] share or change it to `force user = erik`

Then restart smbd

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the **rw** option to your fstab entry?

```
//192.168.1.200/music/ /home/erik/Music-Bespin cifs credentials=/home/erik/.smbcredentials,noperm,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Comment: No dice. Still getting permission denied.